# Overlapping of footer by element with fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have sidebar block, which has position fixed.
I need to fix overlapping of the  footer by this sidebar when I scroll browser's window.

I tried to change the positioning of sidebar to `absolute`, calculate conditions of movement and move it on scroll event of window, but it does not work correctly when I scroll fast.

How can I fix this, problem when scrolling the window fast, or, suggest if there is a js plugin for this?

**Update:**

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c863E/1/

(Footer should not be overlapped by sidebar)

Comment: I'm not sure about the others but I'd like to see some code here. Even better a jsfiddle...

Comment: @otinanai I second that! Provide more information OP!

Comment: a jsfiddle is supposed to show something.. i don't see anything..

Comment: Sorry, I have updated jsfiddle. Block with relative position at the bottom should not be overlapped by block with fixed position if I scroll browser window.

Comment: `#sidebar` should start move along scrolling, when the top of the `#footer` hits to the bottom of the `#sidebar`?

Comment: Is `z-index: 9000` a solution ?

Comment: Teemu, yes, it should start move along scrolling, sidebar should stop movement when it reach top of the footer.

Comment: neustroev.ai, z-index just change visibility, I need to stop movement of sidebar.

Comment: @SergeiStruk I don't get it, `#sidebar` is not moving while scrolling, since it is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the following plugin for this exact task before: http://www.profilepicture.co.uk/sticky-sidebar-jquery-plugin/

It worked perfectly.

Also here is the GitHub project: https://github.com/p-m-p/jQuery-Stickybox

The general term for the solution you need is a sticky sidebar. There are various jQuery plugins and tutorials with varying techniques for achieving this effect. A Google search for "jquery sticky sidebar" will reveal plenty.

Comment: @HugoDozois - The OP did ask for jQuery plugin suggestions... is it not ok to suggest a plugin in that situation? Sorry

Comment: @Joe Spurling, thanks a lot, this plugin is really what I need!