# How to prevent fixed button from overlapping footer area and stop the button on top of where the footer is located

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a button that is fixed on the lower-left side of the screen. I tried to setup in JSFiddle to recreate what I'm trying to do.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="header">header
</div>
<div id="button">button
</div>
<div id="content">some content
</div>
<div id="footer">footer
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#header,#footer{
background-color:red;



}
#content
{
    height:2000px;
}
#footer
{
    height:200px;
}
#button
{
    background-color:gray;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;    
}
```

I have read that, I should use plugins such as scrolltoFixed.js, lockfixed.js
but my problem is I don't know how to use or even where to start editing the javascript.
[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TjNmj/)

I want the button to stop where the footer is, and make it like it was docked.

Comment: It is working in your jsFiddle I think... what do you exactly want to accomplish? :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that by overlapping. I meant that I would somehow stop sliding and stop where the footer starts, and stay there.

Comment: He wants the button to not overlap the footer, preferably stop before the footer.

Comment: @lozadaOmr edit your question with what you wanted..

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230035/overlapping-of-footer-by-element-with-fixed-position

Comment: @Gintas K thank you, I will try to look into your link.

Comment: I've added a new fiddle to my answer, please take a look :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updated now so that it sticks above footer.

[Hope this is what you meant](http://jsfiddle.net/Hf5wH/1/)
The jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
       $('#button').addClass('fixed_button');
   }else{
       $('#button').removeClass('fixed_button');
   }
});
```

CSS:

```
.fixed_button{
    position:absolute !important;
    margin-top:1900px;
    bottom: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: @BeatAlex thank you, this is what I'm trying to accomplish. Will try this.

Comment: @BeatAlex , I noticed that the JavaScript attaches the fixed_button class and that the property margin-top.
But, I think I will be having problems when the content area expands dynamically lets say coming from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning instead. Also, don't use left:0 and right:0. Only use one or the other. Try

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
```

EDIT:
sorry, your code seems to work. What is it you want to do, exactly?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want my button to stop when it hits the footer area. I have read various solutions provided here on stack overflow but I don't think I'm getting nearer on achieving what I'm trying to do.

Comment: ah. I would recommend Javascript for that. Try using jquery; it has event listeners for scrolling that you could use. jQuery is in general one of the easiest and most flexible libraries, actually.

Comment: user2652246: would you kindly recommend a site, where I can start? I have no experience working with JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Oh dear. Well, before working on a real website, I recommend first learning at least Javascript. net.tutsplus.com and w3schools.com are where I started learning. Also, the jQuery documentation: api.jquery.com. If you search up "scroll" on there, you'll see there's an onScroll function.

Comment: no problem! :) We've all had those awkward first few months learning.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and couldn't find any suitable answer here is what I came up with.

```
var $fixed_element = $(".some_element")
if($fixed_element.length){
        var $offset = $(".footer").position().top,
            $wh = $(window).innerHeight(),
            $diff = $offset - $wh,
            $scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
        $fixed_element.css("bottom", Math.max(0, $scrolled-$diff));
    }
```

So now the fixed element would stop right before footer. and will not overlap with it.